# how to Send email using GMail SMTP server from jsp page?

Tags: java, email, jsp, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send an email via GMail's SMTP server from a jsp page but I didn't get the correct result

Answer (score 3):

From JSP, when you submit the form, then you need to call a Java class in which you write code for sending mail using JavaMail. You can find an example here
http://code.geekinterview.com/java/send-email-using-gmail-mail-server.html:

```
//set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;activation.jar;mail.jar
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Mail
{
         String  d_email = "iXmdXr@gmail.com",
            d_password = "****",
            d_host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            d_port  = "465",
            m_to = "iXmdXr@XXXXX.com",
            m_subject = "Testing",
            m_text = "Hey, this is the testing email using smtp.gmail.com.";
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
                String[] to={"XXX@yahoo.com"};
                String[] cc={"XXX@yahoo.com"};
                String[] bcc={"XXX@yahoo.com"};
                //This is for google
                        Mail.sendMail("venkatesh@dfdf.com","password","smtp.gmail.com","465","true",
"true",true,"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory","false",to,cc,bcc,
"hi baba don't send virus mails..","This is my style...of reply..
If u send virus mails..");             
    }

        public synchronized static boolean sendMail(String userName,String passWord,String host,String port,String starttls,String auth,boolean debug,String socketFactoryClass,String fallback,String[] to,String[] cc,String[] bcc,String subject,String text){
                Properties props = new Properties();
                //Properties props=System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", userName);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
                if(!"".equals(port))
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
                if(!"".equals(starttls))
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",starttls);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
                if(debug){
                props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
                }else{
                props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "false");         
                }
                if(!"".equals(port))
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
                if(!"".equals(socketFactoryClass))
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",socketFactoryClass);
                if(!"".equals(fallback))
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", fallback);

        try
        {
                        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            session.setDebug(debug);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setText(text);
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("p_sambasivarao@sutyam.com"));
                        for(int i=0;i<to.length;i++){
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to[i]));
                        }
                        for(int i=0;i<cc.length;i++){
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(cc[i]));
                        }
                        for(int i=0;i<bcc.length;i++){
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(bcc[i]));
                        }
            msg.saveChanges();
                        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
                        transport.connect(host, userName, passWord);
                        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
                        transport.close();
                        return true;
        }
        catch (Exception mex)
        {
            mex.printStackTrace();
                        return false;
        }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Java Mail API](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html).